# How to prove or disprove that the expression is real analyatic.

Tags: real-analysis, implicit-function-theorem

Consider the surface defined by $$ z=2-2\cos(x+y+z) .$$
Express $z$ as a function of $(x,y)$ near $(0,0,0).$ Is this expression real analytic?

I have solved the first part using implicit function theorem. But how to say whether the expression is real analytic or not. Because using implicit function theorem we can say that we can write $z=f(x,y)$.

Comment: Why is this question exactly the same as one posted a half-hour earlier? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2419836/showing-a-function-is-real-analytic

Answer (score 0):

Let $F(x,y,z)=z-2+2\cos(x+y+z)$. The implicit function theorem says: there is a neigborhood $U \subset \mathbb R^2$ of $(0,0)$ and exactly one function $f:U \to \mathbb R$ such that

$F(x,y,f(x,y))=0$ for all $(x,y) \in U$ and $f(0,0)=0$.

Furthermore we have, since $F \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb R^3)$,

$$f \in C^{\infty}(U).$$

Comment: we can show it is holomorphic to obtain it is analytic.

Comment: ??????  $f$ is real valued. If $f$ is holomorphic, then $f$ is constant ! But $f$ is not constant , why ?

Comment: ??? Suppose that $f:U \to \mathbb R$ is holomorphic. Then $f(U) \subset \mathbb R$. Hence $f(U)$ is not open. Therefore $f$ is constant on $U$, say $f(x,y)=c$ on $U$. It follows that $c=2-2\cos(x+y+c)$ for all $(x,y) \in U$. If we differentiate the last equation with respect to $x$, we get $\sin(x+y+c)=0$  for all $(x,y) \in U$, which is absurd.

Comment: $F : \mathbb{C}^3 \to \mathbb{C}, F(x,y,z) =z- 2 + 2 \cos(x+y+z)$, $f : \mathbb{C}^2 \supset U \to \mathbb{C}$, $F(x,y,f(,x,y))=0$. Also in your answer you need $\partial_x F(0,0,0) \ne 0, \partial_y F(0,0,0) \ne 0$ to apply the implicit function theorem and obtain $f$ is $C^\infty$ around $(0,0)$

Comment: In my answer I need $\partial_z F(0,0,0) \ne 0$ and $F(0,0,0)=0$  to apply the implicit function theorem.

Comment: Once again: the problem is a real analysis problem. We have $f \in C^{\infty}(U)$ and $f$ is real valued. Do you agree ? If, yes, how can $f$ be holomorphic without being constant ?

Comment: Of course no $f$ isn't real valued when you extend it to $x,y$ complex

Comment: Then write a friendly letter, adressed to the OP as follows: dear XYZABC, you get the answer to your question, if you have studied complex analysis. Then you extend $x,y,z$ to $x,y,z \in \mathbb C$ and gossip, gossip .... .

Comment: Or you could modify your answer.

Comment: @Fred, Is it enough to show that $f \in C^{\infty}(U)?$ Because as per my knowledge in real analysis $f \in C^{\infty}(U)$ does not implies the analyticity of the function. For example, $f(x)e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}, x\neq 0$ and $0, x=0$. This function is in $C^\infty$ but still not analytic.